# Can you commit or rollback with JDBC Java to store procedures or functions, with commit or rollback of SQL objects?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I intend to consume several Oracle functions, and if all were executed correctly apply commit in Java, otherwise apply rollback to the functions that I consumed.

Java:

```java
String query = "{? = call SAVECLIEN(?)}";
try(CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(query);) {
    cs.execute();
    if (cs.getInt(1) > 0) {
        conn.commit();
    } else {
        conn.rollback();
    }
}
```

Oracle SQL:

```sql
/*OBJECT SQL ORACLE */
CREATE FUNCTION SAVECLIEN(name INTEGER) 
   RETURN NUMBER  IS
BEGIN 
     /*LOGIC OF BUSINESS INSERT ,UPDATES........*/
      INSERT INTO CLIEN VALUES (name);
     /*IF  COMPLETE ALL THE BUSINESS LOGIC APPLY COMMIT OR ROLLBACK*/
COMMIT;
  RETURN 1;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you even bothering with committing and rollbacking on the Java side if the business logic is on the SQL side?

Comment: @TrevorKropp Everything happens in a transaction, so unless you use auto-commit mode, you will have to commit or rollback.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `COMMIT` statement in the procedure. Your attempt to `ROLLBACK` outside the procedure is not going to have any effect because it will `ROLLBACK` to the last `COMMIT` which is after the `INSERT` you are trying to reverse.

Remove the `COMMIT` from the procedure and then you can call an anonymous PL/SQL block which, in turn, calls your function and handles the `COMMIT` and/or `ROLLBACK` logic:

```java
String query = "DECLARE
  value NUMBER;
BEGIN
  value := SAVECLIEN(?);
  IF value > 0 THEN
    COMMIT;
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
  ? := value;
END;";
```

*Note: your output will then be in the 2nd bind variable rather than the 1st.*